# Return only most recent node based on date in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to return the address of a most recent property transaction for every property in my db, along with some details of the transaction. Each property can only have one address but each address may have multiple transactions. So I want the most recent transaction for each property.

This query returns just address of the most recent transaction

```
MATCH (:Property)<-[:ADDRESS_OF]-(a:Address)<-[:PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]-(p:Transaction_details)
return a.id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3, a.postcode, max(p.purchase_date) 
order by a.id
```

but if I want to include some transaction details like this

```
MATCH (:Property)<-[:ADDRESS_OF]-(a:Address)<-[:PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]-(td:Transaction_details)
return a.id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3, a.postcode, max(td.purchase_date), td.purchase_price, td.lease_type 
order by a.id
```

I get all of the transactions returned for each address.

Is there a way to return the transaction details of the most recent transaction, as well as the address details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the most recent `purchase_date` for the given property and then use it as a parameter in the following query:

```
MATCH (:Poperty{id:"abc123"})<-[:ADDRESS_OF]-(:Address)<-[:PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]-(td:Transaction_details)
// get the most recent purchase_date
WITH max(td.purchase_date) AS purchase_date

MATCH (:Poperty{id:"abc123"})<-[:ADDRESS_OF]-(a:Address)<-[:PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]-(td:Transaction_details {purchase_date : purchase_date})
return a.id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3, a.postcode, td.purchase_date, td.purchase_price, td.lease_type 
order by a.id
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I didn't ask the correct question but this approach works for what i meant. I have edited the original question

Answer (score 1):

This simple query should give you info on the last purchase:

```
MATCH (:Property{id:"abc123"})<-[:ADDRESS_OF]-(a:Address)<-[:PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]-(p:Transaction_details)
RETURN a.id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3, a.postcode, p.purchase_date, p.purchase_price, p.lease_type 
ORDER BY p.purchase_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The query orders the results by descending `purchase_date` and return just one result row (for the latest date).

*By the way, I used the label `Property` instead of `Poperty`, whihc seems like a typo.*

Comment: Yes this works, but I didnt quite ask the correct question. Bruno's approach above works for what I actually meant